# Multiple facebook bot with single rasa stack

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm trying to develop a centralized rasa stack for different Facebook pages. All fb pages are of different schools and all schools are using a same software for storing data which is resides in a server. All schools' data are separated by different mysql database. The bot will be used to fetch data for different schools from the respective school's fb page. All the conversation flow will be same, just the db will be different according to the schools. I'm new to rasa. Is there any way to connect all the fb bot to a single rasa stack and differentiate the db according to fb bots when performing the data retrieval from db in custom actions? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible. You can have only one of each output channel. This mean, you would currently need to deploy one Core instance per facebook channel.
I added an [issue](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues/1625) for that to Rasa Core since I think this would be a cool feature for Rasa Core.